# How to Merge image nd arrays in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I want I have 10 arrays of size 128x128, I want to merge them into one array such that I have two arrays in column and 5 in rows i.e., size of output array would be 640 x 256.

```
    a1 = np.random.rand(128,128)
    a2 = np.random.rand(128,128)
    b1 = np.random.rand(128,128)
    b2 = np.random.rand(128,128)
    c1 = np.random.rand(128,128)
    c2 =np.random.rand(128,128)
    d1 = np.random.rand(128,128)
    d2 =np.random.rand(128,128)
    e1 = np.random.rand(128,128)
    e2 =np.random.rand(128,128)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use np.vstack and np.hstack:

```
>>> first_column=np.vstack((a1,b1,c1,d1,e1))
>>> second_column=np.vstack((a2,b2,c2,d2,e2))
>>> out_arr=np.hstack((first_column,second_column))
>>> print(out_arr.shape)
(640, 256)
```

the alternative is to use np.concatenate.